# How to horizontally scroll table with nowrap on <th> elements without overflowing into next column?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working to create a data table that allows for horizontal scrolling of the entire table, while also allowing vertical scrolling of only the `<tbody>`. I need the data in the `<td>` tags to wrap, but I do not want wrapping on the text in the `<th>` elements.

My problem is that I can't seem to get the horizontal scrollbar to actually work - my `<th>` tags seem to be responsive and shrink along with the width of the screen, so my "white-space: nowrap" on the `<th>` elements causes the data to spill out into the column beside it.

I've tried a number of different attempts to get this working with no luck. I'm attaching a jsfiddle with an example of what I'm currently trying:

https://jsfiddle.net/vd0wkf47/

When horizontally shrinking the browser, I want the `<th>` elements to stop shrinking once it reaches the text width. That's when the horizontal scrollbar should kick in for the entire table.

Comment: Please add your example code to the question using the code snippet feature of [edit] rather than offsite.

Answer (score 1):

Set a width on the `th` elements and set `overflow` to `auto`:

```
th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(50% - .5em);           /* half of your thead width */
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* smooth scroll on iOS */
}
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}


thead, tr {
  display:table; 
  width:100%; 
  table-layout:fixed;
}

thead {
  width: calc( 100% - 1em );
}

th {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: calc(50% - .5em);
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: auto;
}

tbody {
  max-height:100px; 
  display:block; 
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: hidden; 
}

td {
  overflow-wrap:
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow-x: scroll; 
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
    <div class="table-wrapper">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th>A Long Long Long Header A Long Long Long Header</th>
          <th>Second Header</th>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
         <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Long Long Longggggggggg Data</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
         </tr>
                  <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Long Long Longggggggggg Data</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Data 1</td>
            <td>Data 2</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u5fpc160/1/